# проблема с phpBB

Tags: php, парсер

Пишу парсер на PHP, переношу форумы в phpBB_forums, в админке отображаются все форумы, а на главной странице только два! Что это может быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Права доступа к форумам настраивайте! Исключительно в этом Ваша проблема! Посмотрите как установлены права доступа к тем форумам которые у Вас видны и настраивайте аналогично на всех остальных!